# Replication in oracle

Tags: replication, oracle11g

I am trying to set up replication on my oracle database. Can someone tell me the steps for this. I am new to oracle. Actually I installed oracle on my machine. I found this link.I have to go through it . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966428.aspx

Can anyone send me any other details or steps to set up replication. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/10/oracle-11g-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-screenshots/

Try to go through the above link which will help to install oracle 11g indesc top systems

Comment: That doesn't come anywhere near close to answering the question, which is about *replication*.